# How to write the Test class for the Apex Trigger

Tags: code-coverage

```
trigger populateContactEmail on Case (before insert , before update){
Set<Id> setConIds = new Set<Id>();

for(Case  obj : trigger.new){
    if(obj.Secondary_Contact__c != null)
        setConIds.add(obj.Secondary_Contact__c);
}

Map<Id , Contact> mapCon = new Map<Id , Contact>([Select Id, Email from Contact where id in: setConIds]);
for(Case obj : trigger.new)
{
    if(obj.Secondary_Contact__c != null)
    {
        //Protecting against bad Ids
        if ( mapCon.containsKey(obj.Secondary_Contact__c)) {
            Contact c = mapCon.get(obj.Secondary_Contact__c);
            obj.Secondary_Contact_Email__c = c.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Unit testing is a common topic, so I've voted to mark this as a duplicate of an existing question. The question I'm pointing you to goes over some of the important concepts, and lists resources that you can use to attempt to write the unit test on your own. One point that I'd like to call more attention to is trailhead. https://trailhead.salesforce.com is, in my opinion, a better resource for starting to learn about new topics (like unit testing) than this site is.

Comment: Read this getting started with test class trailhead module https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro